# How to combine Git branch and tag triggers in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

**Context**

Azure Pipelines supports different kinds of CI triggers ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)).

Example A:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

The pipeline will run if new commits are detected in the master branch.

Example B:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/tags/v*
```

The pipeline will run if new tags beginning with `v` are detected.

I want my pipeline to run when both of the above conditions are true: branch *and* tag.

Example C (not working as desired):

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - refs/tags/v*
```

Combining the two triggers seems to act like an or-condition, not an and-condition.

**Question**

How can I trigger a pipeline on the `master` branch only when there are new `v*` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it is not possible. Following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers):

> If you specify tags in combination with branch filters that include file paths, the trigger will fire if the branch filter is satisfied and either the tag or the path filter is satisfied.

Unfortunatelly adding condition will not help here because we don't have sufficient information. For instance for `tag` trigger we have this

```
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH=refs/tags/release-07
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME=release-07
```

and for `branch` trigger this:

```
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH=refs/heads/master
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME=master
```

And even if you try to check manually branch name with `git branch` you will get:

```
* (HEAD detached at 154ce86)
```

For me this is a good candidate for a feature request at [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I wound up changing my Git branching model and workflow to eliminate the need for the tag check.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this by using [templates and parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters).

**Example**

First, create a `common.yaml` with parameterized tasks and scripts:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: myMessage
    type: string
    default: 'Hello from template!'
  - script: |
      echo ${{ parameters.myMessage }}
```

This yaml can contain any number of parameters, shared tasks and scripts.

Then, create a `master.yaml` for the master branch:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
extends:
  template: common.yml
  parameters:
      myMessage: 'Hello from master!' # Overrides default parameter value
```

Create another `tags.yaml` to run for each new version tag:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/tags/v*
extends:
  template: common.yml
  parameters:
      myMessage: 'Hello from tags!' # Overrides default parameter value
```

Lastly, create two Pipelines within Azure DevOps web interface. Connect one of the Pipelines to `master.yaml` and the other to `tags.yaml`.

With this setup, each trigger is independent with minimal yaml duplication.

Comment: This does not solve the OP's question. With this setup the pipeline is triggered under either condition.